# lmer(): Error in is.nloptr(ret): objective in x0 returns NA

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I tried to build a linear mixed model using the function lmer(), then I get the following error:

```
MOD_1 <- lmer(Variable~fixed_effect*random_effect + (1|random_effect), data = My_data)
Error in is.nloptr(ret) : objective in x0 returns NA
```

Knowing that my random_effect is a "character" vector in origin, even though I convert it to "factor", still get the same error.

I am not an expert in R, and I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Your model is not sensible. Either do `lmer(Variable~fixed_effect + (1|random_effect), data = My_data)` or `lm(Variable~fixed_effect*random_effect, data = My_data)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.